# Function never runs when using Newtonsoft.Json to parse Json

Tags: c#, xamarin, dynamic, json.net, async-await

I'm using NewtonSoft.Json to try to parse a Json response I'm getting from a website in C#. Here's the problem:

```
protected async override Task<bool> DoInBackground() {
    var json = await GetJson();
    return true;
}
```

`GetJson()` is what's responsible for getting the response from the website and returning a string that is the Json response. `DoInBackground()` is part of a custom `AsyncTask` class that handles running tasks in the background.

The above code runs perfectly fine. If I place a breakpoint on the first line inside the function, it stops there and allows me to step through and check that the Json downloaded is correct.

The following code however never executes. As soon as I reference anything from Newtonsoft.Json, the functions stops executing. No breakpoints inside the function will be reached.

```
protected async override Task<bool> DoInBackground() {
    var json = await GetJson();
    dynamic jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
    return true;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I should mention the `DoInBackground()` function runs perfectly in other classes that don't use Newtonsoft.Json. This is the first class where I need to get Json from a server.

Edit: To test if the code was executing without hitting the breakpoint, I tried the following but got no output.

```
protected async override Task<bool> DoInBackground() {
    var json = await GetJson();

    Debug.WriteLine("before");
    dynamic jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
    Debug.WriteLine("after");

    return true;
}
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: @YogeshHShenoy No errors. The function simply doesn't execute.

Comment: What you want your function to return? Curently it is returning Boolean value, you want it to return string?  Then you need to change function's return type and return appropriate value from it

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya The return value is simply a boolean indicating whether or not `DoInBackground()` executed successfully or not. Why does the breakpoint not stop?

Comment: @sjbhalli does the break point hits before calling the function?

Comment: @YogeshHShenoy Yes, breakpoints before the function call are hit.

Comment: @sjbhalli can you try clean the solution, rebuild it and then run the application again. or restart the visual studio

Comment: @YogeshHShenoy Okay cleaning the solution fixed the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case you can simple clear the solution and rebuild it. The application should be running fine because there are no issues with your code.

*Its just that visual studio is using the application which is already build before you made your final modification in code.*

In your case possibly existing build copy does not have the Newtonsoft.Json added.